# Where is the iPad checkbox for "iOS 8.0 and Later"?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having trouble getting my iPad launch screen to appear.

In regards to Xcode 7.2.1, where is the iPad checkbox for "iOS 8.0 and Later"?

I'm currently using Images.xcassets folder and have all the launch screens added for both iPad and iPhone.

The iPhone launch screen is appearing, but not the iPad.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had everything configured correctly with all the Launch Screens.

All I had to do was a Project->Clean and the splash screens started appearing for both iPhone and iPad.

[image]

Comment: I've never worked with an IDE as fickle as Xcode. I never had random things just not work in Visual Studio.